# Simulate clicks in Program with Windows XP Service Pack 2 Compability

Tags: c#, vb.net, click, simulate, user32

I have two scripts that simulate a mouse's left click and closes the program.
The problem that I have is that I can't make the code work well on applications with Windows Combatibility for Windows XP Service Pack 2.

I don't have any problems otherwise.

```
Option Explicit On
Public Class Form1
    Declare Sub mouse_event Lib "user32.dll" (ByVal dwFlags As Long, ByVal dx As Long, ByVal dy As Long, ByVal cButtons As Long, ByVal dwExtraInfo As Long)
    Const MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTDOWN = &H2
    Const MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTUP = &H4
    Const MOUSEEVENTF_RIGHTDOWN = &H8
    Const MOUSEEVENTF_RIGHTUP = &H10

    Private Declare Sub Sleep Lib "kernel32" (ByVal dwMilliseconds As Long)





    Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        Dim i As Integer = 0

        For i = 0 To 100
            Sleep(1000)
            Do_LMouseClick()
        Next

        For Each p As Process In Process.GetProcesses()
            If p.ToString() = "System.Diagnostics.Process (nwmain)" Then
                p.Kill()
            End If
        Next
    End Sub

    Sub Do_LMouseClick()
        Call mouse_event(MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTDOWN, 0, 0, 0, 0)
        Call mouse_event(MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTUP, 0, 0, 0, 0)
    End Sub
End Class
```

And this is in C#

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using WindowsInput;



namespace SimulateClick_nwn_
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {

        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void btn_Comenzar_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++)
            {
                InputSimulator input = new InputSimulator();
                input.Mouse.LeftButtonClick();
                System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(1000);
            }
        }



    }

}
```

How can I make this work?

Comment: I edited your question to make the english a bit easier to read. I don't know anything about C#, so please check over the edit and let me know if I misunderstood what you meant to say.